Challenges with @reactvision/react-viro on Meta Quest 3: Seeking Solutions
Currently, I'm conducting research and development for an app on Meta Quest using React Native. We're exploring the @reactvision/react-viro package for AR/VR functionality. However, we're encountering issues where the app shows a black screen or continuously loads on Meta Quest 3. Even with the starter kit from Viro, we're facing similar loading screen problems. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
I was able to take the build and it worked fine in my testing device ie. the smart phone but it is not working in meta quest 3. I need to know whether the metaquest supportsviro or not?

I have same issue on meta quest 2. My solution is change React Native to Unity 3D for project AR/VR

Do you have any documentation regarding building a new project from scratch in unity 3D as I am not familiar with unity.
